# Find orbits of acting permutation subgroup on cartesian product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Well, let $G$ be a group, $X$ a set, we have action of a group on a set. So, in my case, $G = ⟨(12), (1234)⟩$, $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. My task is to find orbits of a group acting on $X$, $X \times X$ (Cartesian product). But I have some difficulties with $X \times X$. How can I find it? I would be grateful for your prompt reply!

Upd: Thanks for replying, but I have some problems with $X \times X$. I know that order of $⟨(12), (1234)⟩$. Should I apply each permutation to each element? So, $(12)$ to $(1, 1)$, $(12)$ to $(1, 2)$, . . . , $(1234)$ to $(1, 1)$, $(1234)$ to $(1, 2)$ and so on. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply, for example, $(12)$ to 1, you get 2, and if you try again you get 1. That means the orbit of 1 under the action of $(12)$ is $\{1,2\}$. On the other hand $(12)$ fixes 3 and 4, it does not move them.

The action of $G$ on $X$ extends naturally to $X \times X$ via $$(g,(p,q)) \mapsto (gp,gq). $$
So now you can try to see what the action of $(12)$ on the pair $(2,3)$ is. $(2,3) \mapsto (1,3) \mapsto (2,3)$ and so on, so the orbit of $(2,3)$ is $\{(1,3),(2,3)\}.$ You can play with the other pairs and permutations in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find orbits of $X \times X$ except of applying each permutation to each element?

Comment: You can for example start with the orbits of the elements of $X$ and conclude what the orbits of the elements in $X \times X$ are, saving some computations.